# How to add new reference programmatically in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5

I want to add a reference of the dll files programatically in C#.I’m facing a scenario, to convert the list of project from framework 1.1 to framework 3.5. while converting this, the framework 3.5, shows some absolute methods and I need to convert this. Even I converted this absolute methods.

Now I need to add a new reference to this converted project via programmatically.

While converting itself I need to add a new reference to the project. Is there any way to add through C# code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just edit your project files(`csproject`). inside its simple XML

looks like this:

```
<Reference Include="log4net">
    <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.2.0.0\lib\net40-client\log4net.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I would use simple search & replace. but of course you can write C# code for this.